# TableRow onSelectChange selects correctly Table Group but not single Row

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, typescript

I have the following Array with Objects in my React TypeScript app for a table.

Inside this table I have grouped table rows (for each category) and in my case I have a select box with an event which should then select all items with the same category:

[image: example table]

This is my data:

```
[
    {
        "id": "6f16bc72-9747-4a2d-b165-14ef358762e6",
        "name": "diesel-south-ullam-photoshop",
        "version": "1.12.40",
        "visible": true,
        "category": "libraries",
        "status": "unselected",
        "searchQuery": "",
        "type": "",
        "filterStatus": {
            "status": "all",
            "category": "all"
        },
        "page": 1
    },
    {
        "id": "aaf6b8f8-0e7f-4420-87dc-fec9451d7935",
        "name": "coupe-when",
        "version": "1.14.8",
        "visible": true,
        "category": "software-components",
        "status": "unselected",
        "searchQuery": "",
        "type": "",
        "filterStatus": {
            "status": "all",
            "category": "all"
        },
        "page": 1
    },
    {
        "id": "3e8797e6-9da7-47d6-a7d6-c2828bf69989",
        "name": "wagon-not-classical",
        "version": "2.15.14",
        "visible": true,
        "category": "software-components",
        "status": "unselected",
        "searchQuery": "",
        "type": "",
        "filterStatus": {
            "status": "all",
            "category": "all"
        },
        "page": 1
    }
]
```

This is how a TableRow of a TableGroup is getting rendered:

```
<OwcTableRow
  data-testid={`table-row-${elementIndex}`}
  key={row.id + "-123"}
  selectable
  selected={row.status === "selected"}
  onSelectChange={() => {
    const selectedCategoryItems = tableGroup
      .find((group) => group.key === row.category)
      .elements.filter((singleItem) => singleItem.visible);

    // Determine if all items in the category are currently selected
    const allSelected = selectedCategoryItems.every(
      (itemCat) => itemCat.status === "selected"
    );

    // Toggle the selection status of items within the category
    const updatedData = data.map((newItem) => {
      if (newItem.category === row.category) {
        return {
          ...newItem,
          status: allSelected ? "unselected" : "selected",
        };
      }
      return newItem;
    });

    setData(updatedData);
  }}
>
```

Table Group is created within this function:

```
const tableGroup = React.useMemo(
  (): Array<any> => [
    {
      key: 'libraries',
      label: tkeys.overview.libraries.cardTitle,
      elements: getByCategory('libraries'),
    },
    {
      key: 'software-components',
      label: tkeys.overview.softwareComponents.cardTitle,
      elements: getByCategory('software-components'),
    },
  ],
  [getByCategory, i18n.language, tkeys]
);
```

The Problem is that I can select the Checkbox for "Libraries (0 of 1)" and it selects the tabe row.

But clicking on "Software components (0 of 2)" checkbox in the Table Group I can select both table rows but clicking on a single row also toggles the second row which is incorrect.

Comment: How are category rows represented in data?

Comment: I advanced a bit with my solution and changed the code for my question @Lesiak

Answer (score 1):

My React is a bit rusty, but I believe that a modification to the `updateData` function should do the trick.

```
const updatedData = data.map((newItem) => {
  if (newItem.category === row.category) {
    if (newItem.id === row.id) {
      // Toggle the selection status of the clicked row
      return {
        ...newItem,
        status: newItem.status === "selected" ? "unselected" : "selected",
      };
    }

    // Update the status of category header based on selected items
    const selectedCategoryItems = tableGroup
      .find((group) => group.key === row.category)
      .elements.filter((singleItem) => singleItem.visible);

    const allSelected = selectedCategoryItems.every(
      (itemCat) => itemCat.status === "selected"
    );

    // Update category header status based on selected items
    const updatedItem = {
      ...newItem,
      status: allSelected ? "selected" : "unselected",
    };

    return updatedItem;
  }

  return newItem;
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
Unfortunately it did not change the behaviour. I just checked Chrome debugger and the onSelectChange is getting called three times. The first two calls are selecting the items correctly and for the last time the `updatedData` has the items again with `unselected`. 

Right now it looks for me as the `setData(updatedData);` is somehow "too Slow" so that the `data` is not updated when the change event is getting called? Does this make sense?

The `onSelectChange={() => {` consists now on your answer and I only added `setData(updatedData);` at the end - is this ok?

Comment: The slowness problem, I think, it's because for every click you search the whole table multiple times. Try to work on that. See if you can reduce the number of searched and filters at the table. For instance, use a counter on the Category Headers that you add or subtract according to the children selection; add a reference to the Category Header in the children. Things like these. Just because you can do something with the tools of the language, doesn't mean you should.